# python tkinter Can I make a widget in pixel? with text?

Tags: python, tkinter

I want to make a text widget in pixel size. But always set on font size.

Here is my code:

```
 import tkinter as tk
 root = tk.Tk()
 test_btn = tk.Button(root, text="test", height=10, width=10)
 test_btn.pack()
 root.mainloop()
```

I want to use pixel, but i can't so, I am using "place" method, so my code looks dirty.
I want to change them to "pixel size" and pack.

Comment: assign a one pixel image to it and set `compound='center'`.

Comment: Thx!! Can I ask  one more question? i want to make root_background blur. window.wait_visibility(window)
window.wm_attributes('-alpha',0.3) <--- Here is my code. it works on window but i have to do this on linux debian.. Is there a way to do it?

Comment: '-alpha' should work in tk 8.6 under Linux.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `width` attribute is in units of characters if the button has text, but is in units of pixels if the button has an image. So, you can add a small transparent image to the button and set the `compound` option to allow both text and image at the same time. When you do that, `width` will be interpreted as pixels.

Example:

```
image = tk.PhotoImage(width=1, height=1)
button = tk.Button(root, image=image, text="Hello, world", compound="center",width=300)
```